# Master detail application, passing object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, swift2

I'm sure I'm overlooking something basic, but I'm getting frustrated over this. I am unable to access the properties of the object selected in the row and passed to the detail view. Here's the relevant code :

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    return true
}
```

MasterViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = matchups[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            controller.detailItem = matchups[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (detailViewController != nil) {
        self.detailViewController!.detailItem = matchups[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

DetailViewController:

```
var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}


func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text =  detail //** This is where the problem lies **//
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Apple template code. I've also tried following web tutorials that use alternate methods and I'm still running into problems. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test is String, DetailItem is AnyObject?. You need to cast detailItem to a required type before assigning it.

What is supposed detailItem type? Is it just a string? In such case you can write as? in your if let definition, it would be enough.

Comment: I knew I was leaving out something basic. Thank you very much.